# If $x^{x^4}=4$, then what is the value of $x^{x^2}+x^{x^8}$?

Tags: power-towers

If $x^{x^4}=4$, then what is the value of $x^{x^2}+x^{x^8}$?

I tried to simplify it using exponentiation and logs, and even just algebraic manipulation..But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Linear algebra? To clarify, the expression is $x^{(x^4)}$ and so on? If so, then note that the real roots of $x^{(x^4)}=4$ are $±\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Isn't the domain of $x^{x^4}$ should be $x>0$?

Comment: Yes. @lulu That's what the question means.

Comment: Note that if a number $x$ satisfies $x^4=4$, then it also satisfies $x^{x^4}=4$

Comment: Yea. Agreed @nospoon

Comment: A cute trick for this kind of thing: if $x^{x^4}=4$ then $(x^4)^{x^4}=x^{4x^4}=(x^{x^4})^4=4^4$.  This makes it easy to spot the solution $x^4=4$.  ([similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339593/21467))

Comment: Excellent observation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just note that $x^{x^4}$ is increasing for $x>1$ and is $<1$ for $x<1$. The unique positive solution to $x^{x^4}=4$ is $x=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Yea.... got it.

Answer (score 4):

$x^{x^{4}}=4$. Let us replace 4 of the exponent of left hand side by $x^{x^{4}}$ then equation becomes $x^{x^{x^{x^{4}}}}=4$. Repeating this process infinitely we get $x^{x^{x^{x^{x..}}}}=4$. Now We replace the exponent of left hand side by 4 and equation now become $x^{4}=4$ hence $x=\sqrt{2}$ or $x=-\sqrt{2}$ . So $x^{x^{2}}+x^{x^{8}} =258$

Comment: Nice observation and method.